# How to retrieve all properties of an asset using the QueryBuilder Api

Tags: aem, query-builder

When i use the below query on [AEM QueryDebug](http://localhost:4502/libs/cq/search/content/querydebug.html)

```
path=/content/dam/we-retail  
type=dam:Asset  
p.limit=-1  
p.nodedepth=2  
p.hits=full  
p.guesstotal=true
```

And the formed [URL/JSON QueryBuilder](http://localhost:4502/bin/querybuilder.json?p.guesstotal=true&p.hits=full&p.limit=-1&p.nodedepth=2&path=%2Fcontent%2Fdam%2Fwe-retail&type=dam%3AAsset) link.

I can see all the properties for each asset including jcr:content, metadata as below:

[image]

I need to return the same result to service/endpoint i'm building on AEM for a customer. When I translate the same above query into Query builder API

```
queryParamsMap.put("type", "dam:Asset");  
queryParamsMap.put("p.limit", "-1");  
queryParamsMap.put("p.nodedepth", "2");  
queryParamsMap.put("p.hits", "full");  
queryParamsMap.put("p.guessTotal", "true");
```

How can i retrieve all the values?

```
SearchResult result = query.getResult();  
for (final Hit hit : result.getHits()) {  
  Resource resource = hit.getResource();  
  Asset asset = resource.adaptTo(Asset.class);
```

If i use `asset.getMetadata()`, we can see only the properties under `jcr:content\metadata` but not the other properties.

and

if i use `ValueMap properties = resource.getValueMap();` we can retrieve all the asset properties (like jcr:path, jcr:primaryType etc) but not "metadata".

Is there any way to get all the values for an Asset node?

Comment: Properties are specific to a node in JCR structure. You can write your own wrapper to merge the properties from the jcr: content and metadata nodes. There is no OOTB API to do this if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Why "-1" for this question?

Answer (score 1):

After some research, i found the below solution. Posting here for others reference.

As mentioned by @Imran-Saeed , there is no method that will return all the properties of an Asset (or a Node. Asset is also a node) in AEM. We have to do this in a combination.

1. Get all the top level properties (Node root level). These include `jcr:created`, `jcr:createdBy`, etc.
2. Get all `jcr:content` level properties. These include `cq:name`, `cq:lastModified`, etc
3. Get all `jcr:content\metadata` level properties. These include `dc:title`, any custom metadata etc.
4. You can add all these to another new `ValueMap` that can hold all the properties of a particular Node/Asset.

[image]

Below is a code snippet:

```
Resource resource;
ValueMap mainProperties;
ValueMap assetMetadataProperties;
Resource metadataResource;
ValueMap jcrProperties;
Resource jcrdataResource;
ValueMap allProperties;

for (Hit hit : result.getHits()) {
        //LOGGER.info("\n********Hit path="+hit.getPath()+", title="+hit.getTitle());
        resource = hit.getResource();

        if(null!=resource){
            mainProperties = resource.getValueMap();

            // Add JCR Properties
            jcrdataResource = resource.getChild("jcr:content");
            jcrProperties = ResourceUtil.getValueMap(jcrdataResource);

            // Add Metadata properties
            metadataResource = resource.getChild("jcr:content/metadata");
            assetMetadataProperties = ResourceUtil.getValueMap(metadataResource);

            // Adding all togethe
            allProperties = new ValueMapDecorator(new HashMap());
            allProperties.putAll(hit.getProperties());
            allProperties.putAll(mainProperties); // Includes jcr:created createdDate etc.
            allProperties.put("jcr:path",hit.getPath()); //Add Path
            allProperties.putAll(jcrProperties);
            allProperties.putAll(assetMetadataProperties);

            //LOGGER.debug("All Asset Properties="+new Gson().toJson(allProperties));               
        }
    }
```

**Note**

1. `jcr:path` is not returned by any of the above. So i had to explicitly add it using `hit.getPath`
2. The name of the node or Asset name can be pulled from `hit.getTitle()`. Ofcourse this is also returned as part of `cq:name`.
3. There are other ways to get the properties as well. One aother way is to get the `Node` and retrieve the properties. `com.day.cq.search.result.Hit` has a method `getNode()` that returns a `java.jcr.Node` interface and you can use that get to fetch the properties.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get all the properties of an AEM asset from the dam:Asset node itself to the metadata node (jcr:content/metadata) is using **Apache Sling Models** and adapting each resource returned by your query to this model.

For example:

```
@Model(adaptables=Resource.class)
public class MyAsset{

    @Inject
    @Named("jcr:created")
    private String createdDate;

    @Inject
    @Named("jcr:createdBy")
    private String createdBy;

    @Inject
    @Named("jcr:content/jcr:lastModified")
    @Optional
    private String lastModified;

    @Inject
    @Named("jcr:content/metadata/dc:title")
    @Optional
    private String title;

    @Inject
    @Named("jcr:content/metadata/dc:description")
    @Optional
    private String description;

    @PostConstruct
    protected void init() {
         // You can code here any task needed to be executed after all the injections of the model are done
    }

  //getters and setters...

}
```

**Note** that you can specify any property of any descendant node of the resource using the annotation @Named.

I will suggest you use this approach if you need **specific** and **few** properties of the resource.  If you need **all properties** I think the approach you found is better because you do not need to create a model to maintain all properties.

Using the model the final code will be:

```
for (Hit hit : result.getHits()) {
      Resource resource = hit.getResource();
        if(resource!=null){
         MyAsset myAsset = resource.adaptTo(MyAsset.class);
        Logger.info("The asset {} was modified on {}", myAsset.getTitle(), myAsset.getLastModified());
        }
    }
```

For more info about Sling Model you can refer to:

https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/models.html